# Sonar plugin coding: How do I test if a statement is a method invocation?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am writing a few rules, and one is to alert the usage of `indexOf()` in a for-each statement. [Here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6a28028bfaafeadd3765) is what I have so far, but method invocation and assignment are considered expressions, not statements, and the `BodyTree` class returns a group of `StatementTree`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maybe put your code directly into your request, it will be easier for readers to understand the rest.

A few comments:

- Instead of using  `if (st instanceof BlockTree)`, prefer using `if(st.is(Tree.Kind.BLOCK))`.
- As you registered to `foreach` statements, you don't need to use `instance of`. Your tree is a necessarily a `ForEachStatementTree` when entering the `visitNode` method. You then simply have to cast it.

Now, note that you approach is probably not the simplest one and it will be probably too complex to handle all the cases that way. You may want to try this approach:

- Register to `foreach` trees **and** `method invocation` trees (`Tree.Kind.METHOD_INVOCATION`)
- When you are visiting a `foreach` node, store the expression corresponding to the collection used for the `foreach` (or the corresponding symbol...)
- When you are visiting a method invocation, check that you are in a `foreach` and that the method name is `indexof`. You can check that you are calling it on the same collection as the one used for your `foreach`.
- Add an issue if required
- In order to keep an eye on nested calls, override method `SubscriptionVisitor.leaveNode(Tree tree)`, which will be called when leaving subscribed nodes, and unstack if the node is a `foreach` tree.

Comment: So once I store the fact that I have entered a for-each statement, how do I register the fact that I have left it? There may be nested for-each statements and I would like to handle those as well.

Comment: Simply override method `SubscriptionVisitor.leaveNode(Tree tree)`, which will be called when leaving subscribed nodes and unstack it if the node is a `foreach`tree.